Tensorflow Matrices match error when applying gaussian blur module
I am having a problem with the gaussian blur of tensorflow.js.
Tried to apply the gaussian blur to a video but the best I can do is get  the colors inverted.
The 5 by 5 matrix kernel I have seems to be accepted as the size to use when applying gaussian blur to a frame.
            const video = document.getElementById('video');
            const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const uploadForm = document.getElementById('uploadForm');

            uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                const formData = new FormData(uploadForm);

                fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.file) {
                        const fileURL = `http://localhost:3000/${data.file}`;
                        video.src = fileURL;
                        video.addEventListener('play', () => {
                            processFrame();
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.error('Upload failed:', data.msg);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            });

            // Define the 5x5 Gaussian kernel as a flat array and shape it to 4D
            const gaussianKernel = tf.tensor4d([
                1/256, 4/256, 6/256, 4/256, 1/256,
                4/256, 16/256, 24/256, 16/256, 4/256,
                6/256, 24/256, 36/256, 24/256, 6/256,
                4/256, 16/256, 24/256, 16/256, 4/256,
                1/256, 4/256, 6/256, 4/256, 1/256
            ], [5, 5, 1, 1]); // Shape to [filterHeight, filterWidth, inChannels, outChannels]

            const processFrame = () => {
                if (video.paused || video.ended) return;

                ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const frame = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                console.log("Processing frame...");

                // Convert image data to float32 before applying Gaussian blur
                const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(frame).toFloat();
                console.log("Original Tensor:", tensor.shape);

                const channels = tensor.split(3, 2);
                const blurredChannels = channels.map(channel => {
                    console.log("Channel Shape:", channel.shape);

                    // Expand dimensions to 4D for conv2d
                    const expandedChannel = channel.expandDims(0).expandDims(-1);
                    console.log("Expanded Channel Shape:", expandedChannel.shape);

                    // Apply convolution
                    const blurredChannel = tf.conv2d(expandedChannel, gaussianKernel, 1, 'same');
                    console.log("Blurred Channel Shape:", blurredChannel.shape);

                    return blurredChannel.squeeze();
                });

                const blurredTensor = tf.concat(blurredChannels, 2);
                const blurredImageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(blurredTensor.dataSync()), canvas.width, canvas.height);
                console.log("Blurred Tensor Shape:", blurredTensor.shape);

                ctx.putImageData(blurredImageData, 0, 0);
                requestAnimationFrame(processFrame);
            };

it gets to the 'expanded channel shape' step then spits out an error
Uncaught Error: Error in conv2d: input must be rank 4, but got rank 5.
